# Traduction de « blows it away »

Tags: traduction, anglais, poésie

C'est un problème de traduction anglais français.

Voici un poème de Richard Brautigan :

```
"Floating Chandeliers"
    Sand is crystal
    like the soul.
    The wind blows
         it away.
```

Comment traduire **The wind blows it away** ?

- Le vent le souffle au loin ?
- Le vent (pour le vent, je pense que c'est bon) le souffle loin ?

La traduction proposée par Nicolas Richard dans le fascicule *Journal Japonais* aux éditions *Le Castor Astral* (pub gratuite) est *Le vent l'emporte au loin* mais, à l'oral, je préfèrerais *Le vent l'emporte loin*, mais je voudrais rester fidèle, si ce n'est au traducteur, au moins à l'auteur, et je suis un peu perplexe devant la traduction de *blows* en *emporte*.

Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Pour ceux qui, comme moi, pédalent en anglais, la traduction proposée de l'ensemble est :

```
Chandeliers flottants

Le sable est cristal
comme l'âme.
Le vent l'emporte 
   au loin.
```

Comment: Certains pensent que [le vent les portera](http://youtu.be/NrgcRvBJYBE), mais tout disparaîtra.

Comment: Oui moi aussi j'avais pensé à ça :-) Heureusement, Brautigan n'est qu'un poète semi-maudit, lui, ouf pour nos consciences (et c'est sans doute mieux, l'art a quand même ses limites). Et si quelqu'un pouvait avoir une réponse...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je vois deux difficultés ici : la première est la faculté de l’anglais d’utiliser un verbe décrivant l’action et une préposition décrivant ces conséquences. C’est le « away », ici, qui nous force à utiliser cet « au loin » qui limite bien plus nos choix de verbe que dans la langue originale. La seconde est que le « it » peut très bien se référer au sable ou à l’âme. Or, en français, le genre fera qu’il nous faudra utiliser soit « le », soit « la » qui détermineront si l’on parle de l’âme ou du sable, et briseront le parallélisme. Restent donc les verbes commençant par une voyelle qui nous donneront l’échappatoire de l’apostrophe.

Du coup, je ne vois guère ce qu’il reste à part « emporter » et « emmener ». « Déplacer » pourrait convenir mais est tellement moins fort, et ne commence pas par la voyelle tant nécessaire. Reformuler en utilisant « éloigner » fait à nouveau perdre la dimension d’impuissance que contient « emporter » (et, tel que je le comprend, « *blow away* »). J’aime « éparpiller », mais je pense qu’il contient un sens qui n’est pas présent dans l’original.

Bref, non, je ne vois pas comment améliorer la traduction. Mais le contraire serait inquiétant, je ne suis ni traducteur professionnel ni même féru de poésie. Et rien ne porte à croire que Nicolas Richard ait fait un travail médiocre.

Comment: Merci pour les explications de cet étrange blow traduit par emporter. Je suis conscient que la traduction de Nicolas Richard est bonne sur l'ensemble du livre, et c'est pour ça que je posais la question, car j'hésite à prendre des initiatives :-). Et loin / au loin ?

Comment: La réponse de Evpok est également excellente, mais je ne peux malheureusement donner "bonne réponse" qu'à une seule. Je l'ai donnée à qui avait le moins de points :-) Et en plus je me félicite d'avoir posé la question, car j'ai appris plein de trucs. Merci à tous !

Answer (score 7):

Le français et l'anglais modernes ne codent en général pas de la même façon le chemin d'un mouvement et son mode. Pour faire simple, le français est à cadrage verbal, c'est à dire qu'il indique dans la direction dans le verbe et le mode dans les compléments circonstanciels ou pas du tout: ici, *emporter* implique qu'on s'éloigne du point de référence et le mode est omis.

L'anglais, en revanche¹, est à cadrage satellitaire, et indique donc dans le verbe le mode du mouvement et dans les satellites (en général des particules verbales) sa direction. Ici *blow* indique le mode et *away* la direction.

La traduction proposée est donc correcte du point de vue du sens² et de la structure de la langue, et en général on pourra difficilement faire mieux. Comme le mode de déplacement est donné en français par des compléments circonstanciels, donc facultatif, on l'omet en général, sauf s'il est important pour le propos, et le préciser ne passe pas toujours. 
Maintenant, si tu pense qu'on y perd à ne pas préciser *blow*, on peut quand même essayer :

> Le vent le souffle au loin

marche, même si c'est un peu inhabituel et

> Le souffle du vent l'emporte au loin

est tout à fait correct, même ça altère légèrement le sens.

---

1. Et on se trompe rarement à chercher la revanche contre les anglois
2. même si *away* n'implique pas toujours *très loin*, mais ici ça semble marcher.

Answer (score 1):

Le sable, cristallin, tel une âme. 
Le vent l’amène ailleurs.

Answer (score 1):

> Le vent le disperse

Car je pense qu'on parle du sable ici.

Origine de la réponse: un prof d'anglais. Car oui, celle là est plutôt dodue.

Answer (score 1):

*Essai :*

> Le balancement des lustres
>   L'âme est sable adamantin, 
>   le souffle du vent l'emporte.

*Traduire l’atmosphère*

- En partant de l'idée que le vent anime le mouvement des lustres du plafond
- en suggérant que ce mouvement hypnotique déclenche une rêverie
- en proposant que le rêve allie lumière, reflets dans le cristal
- en continuant sur une allégorie de l'âme.

*Revenir à la source des mots*

- En partant de la construction anglaise habituellement inversée,
- en rapprochant l'âme du diamant plutôt que du cristal,
- en rattachant le vent à sa source et non à son action,
- en laissant l'ambiguïté sur le *it* à travers le *l'*.
- en gardant le rythme.

*Pour répondre à la question et rester dans la sphère poétique :*

> **Le souffle du vent l'emporte**.

*Edit*

Si l'on pense que le sable est transformé en diamant (cristal) par l'âme et qu'ils restent des 'objets'

> **Le souffle du vent l'emmène**

Si l'on pense que l'âme sublime le sable, que la rêverie prend une nouvelle dimension subjective.

Comment: Hum... là je trouve que c'est un autre poème, certes inspiré par le premier... c'est vrai que c'est un façon de réfléchir à un poème, mais moins de répondre à une question :-) Mais j'aime bien quand même vos remarques, j'aime bien réfléchir à un poème :-) Merci.

Comment: @Istao C'est le grand problème de la traduction littérale et la traduction poétique, s'attacher à l'objectivité méthodologique ou à la subjectivité. Mais c'est bien le souffle qui œuvre ici tant par le vent que par l'inspiration du poème. Je ne pourrais rien proposer dans le sens français->anglais tels les exemples http://fleursdumal.org/poem/113

Comment: @Istao Je viens de retrouver la source. (http://divinentd.com/richard-brautigan/june-30-june-30.html) Même si cela a été écrit à Tokyo, les textes n'ont ni la force des haïku, ni la profondeur du zen.